# Is that bad to declare a public final method in java

Tags: java

I want to declare a public method in a base class that can't not be overwritten by child class.

Is it clean to declare this method public final?

Comment: It's bad to declare just about any method in Java B-)

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's clean or not. It's the only way to do what you want.

Comment: This is a broad question that is open to interpretation.  Narrow the question if it is at all possible.

Comment: What makes you think that this could be not “clean”?  Do you have any specific concerns?  That's just what `final` is there for.

Comment: Why would that be bad? A final method implies that it cannot be overridden - it does not imply that it is not inherited. Inheritance is still a good thing in certain cases. :-)

Comment: Generally, you want to avoid inheritance anyway. Just make sure that overriding that method really doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are legitimate reasons to want a method final. Base object references can also point to derived class instances. So if a method is getting a Base class reference, it may actually be pointing to a DerivedFromBase object.

```
int SomeMethod(Base aBase)
{
     ...
     double value = aBase.Calculate(a,b,c);
     ...
}
```

If the derived class overrides the Calculate method so that it operates differently than the way Base does it, it could potentially cause SomeMethod to behave incorrectly, as it was written to expect Calculate to behave the way Base implemented it.

Making the Calculate method final ensures that the derived classes don't change the behavior of the Calculate method, which ensures that SomeMethod will behave the same whether it is passed a Base object or any object derived from Base.

Answer (score 0):

About as clean as it gets. The final Modifier declares that the method or variable cannot be subclassed.

From wikipedia

*

> A final class cannot be subclassed. Doing this can confer security and
>   efficiency benefits, so many of the Java standard library classes are
>   final, such as java.lang.System and java.lang.String. All methods in a
>   final class are implicitly final.

*

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Final_%28Java%29

Generally speaking its best to avoid using final where you might have a suspicion that the object will not remain constant.